# How Convert byte[] to varchar?

Tags: c#, mysql

```
SELECT Trainer.id AS idTrainer, surname, lastname, name,  
if(month = '', 'NO',month) as monthT, quarter, halfyear, year, id_Person, photo
FROM Trainer, Person
WHERE Trainer.id_Person = Person.id
```

`if(month = '', 'NO',month) as monthT` in phpmyadmin return good or 'no' or month

In a C# returns `byte[]`, but I need return `NO` if month is empty or else return the `month`.

My C# code looks like this:

```
string sql = @" SELECT Trainer.id AS idTrainer, surname, lastname, name,  if(month = '', 'NO',month) as monthT, quarter, halfyear, year, id_Person, photo
                FROM Trainer, Person
                WHERE Trainer.id_Person = Person.id";
using (MySqlConnection connection = ConnectToDataBase.GetConnection())
{
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

    connection.Open();
    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
}
```

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Can you post the CREATE TABLE statement? Does C# return byte[] instead of string, or do you want it to return byte[] instead of string? Why did you use empty '' rather than _NULL_?

Comment: how convert is byte[] to string ... means sql

Comment: @Cesar: The question is: On C# it returns an `byte[]` object instead of `string`. He is expecting `good` or `no`. So he is asking what's wrong. @simply: Please show your C# code for more context.

Comment: @BrunoLM: thanks, it's clearer now, but I agree that some C# code would help.

Comment: @Cesar,@BrunoLM:So what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While researching I have found out that there is the bug with VARCHAR using CAST. The solution is to use CHAR instead of VARCHAR.

Proof links:

[Using Conversion Functions](http://www.geeksengine.com/database/single-row-functions/conversion-functions.php)

[Bug #34564 CAST does not accept varchar type](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34564)

[Cast Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no MySql expert but why you don't try to cast?

```
CAST(if(month = '', 'NO',month) AS VARCHAR) AS monthT
```

more here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR) as monthT, quarter, halfyear, year, id_Person, photo
                 ' at line 1

Comment: As I said, I'm no MySql expert and I don't have any MySql installed. It was just a hint for you how to solve it... I'm sure you can figure it out how to make it run ;-)